# Simple PytorchBenchmark from transformers lib of Huggingface script gives CUDA initialisation error

Tags: python, pytorch, benchmarking, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to run a simple benchmark script from the `transformers` [lib from Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/transformers/benchmarks.html), but it fails due to a CUDA error, which leads to another error:

```
1 / 1
Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cbarkhof/code-thesis/Experimentation/Benchmarking/benchmarking-models-claartje.py", line 12, in <module>
    benchmark.run()
  File "/home/cbarkhof/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/benchmark/benchmark_utils.py", line 674, in run
    memory, inference_summary = self.inference_memory(model_name, batch_size, sequence_length)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The script simply follows the example like shown on [this page](https://huggingface.co/transformers/benchmarks.html):

```
from transformers import PyTorchBenchmark, PyTorchBenchmarkArguments

benchmark_args = PyTorchBenchmarkArguments(models=["bert-base-uncased"],
                                           batch_sizes=[8],
                                           sequence_lengths=[8, 32, 128, 512],
                                           save_to_csv=True,
                                           log_filename='log',
                                           env_info_csv_file='env_info')

benchmark = PyTorchBenchmark(benchmark_args)
benchmark.run()
```

If anyone can point me to why this might be happening. Please let me know :). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to the CUDA runtime [not supporting process forking](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html#cuda-in-multiprocessing) which is the default method of multiprocessing in PyTorch. The suggested workaround is to call `torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')` before importing `transformers`, but in my experiments this raises an `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object` error.

If you're happy with the script running as a single process when using GPUs you can pass the `multi_process=False` arg, or `--no_multi_process` flag if using the command line script. Alternatively, if running this on CPU only without CUDA, you should be able to make use of multiple cores and passing the `cuda=False` arg or `--no_cuda` flag should also work.